# Is a flyback diode necessary with a relay module for operating a Solenoid valve?

Tags: microcontroller, relay, solenoid-valve

Assuming I have a relay module (I'm not sure about its features) that is connected to a 12 V DC solenoid valve and should be operated by a microcontroller.

- Do I need a flyback diode connected with the relay module?
  -Do relay modules usually include flyback diodes?
- What about the solenoid valve - does it need its own flyback diode or is it unnecessary?
- Finally, do I need to make sure that opto-coupling is provided?

Comment: DC or AC solenoid valve? [Edit] the details into your question.

Comment: @Transistor I've just edited it. Thanks very much for your concern.

Comment: The following posts might help: (1) Flyback diodes for solenoid": https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=230984&start=25#p1417740, (2) "Flyback diodes selection":
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=230984&start=25#p1417554

Comment: What's a "relay module"? Could be anything from a plastic bin with a relay inside to a PLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the relay module will include a flyback diode, but that diode is only foir the relay itself.  you will need another diode for the solenoid.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is 1N4007 fine as a flyback diode for a 12 V/ 2 A DC solenoid valve? and will connecting a flyback diode dramatically slow down the operation of the solenoid valve?

Comment: 1N400x are good for 1A average current, used with a 2A solenoid it will see 2A peak current (and usually much less) so it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your useful info. Excuse me, if the relay module provides optocoupling, do I still need to use a separate power source for the relay module (VCC) other than that of the microcontroller?

Comment: the best I cab say there is maybe,